# pass in environment variables when running a local Docker image

Tags: windows, docker, powershell

I have the following docker image:

```
REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server   2017-latest         a9ac6b268134        2 months ago        1.49GB
```

I am trying to run my local version, rather than re-downloading. The following does start, but then dies because it needs to accept the Eula. Also it needs an Sql server password to be useful:

`docker run -i -t a9ac6b268134`

So I am trying to pass those in. That's where I'm failing. This is one of my attempts. What am I missing?

`docker run -i -t a9ac6b268134 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Aaaaaa1!" -p 1433:1433`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try passing the image id at the end?

```
docker run -i -t  -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Aaaaaa1!" -p 1433:1433 a9ac6b268134
```

Source: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server